# Couldn't find Tag while searching a product with tags in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

i have multiple tags for each product in my rails project and i wanted to search my products through tags and i've been getting the following error when i search:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#index

Couldn't find Tag

I have used a tags model to store the tags and a taggings model to connect tags and products table(with many to many relationship)

PRODUCTS_CONTROLLER

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
     if params[:tag]
    @products = Product.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = current_user.products.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:filetype, :title, :img_url, :description, :all_tags, :price, :uploaded_by, :tutorial_url)
    end
end
```

PRODUCT MODEL

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

    has_attached_file :img_url, styles: { large: "800x600>", medium: "320x200>", thumb: "100x80#" }, validate_media_type: false
    validates_attachment_content_type :img_url, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

    def self.tagged_with(name)
        Tag.find_by!(name: name).products
    end

    def all_tags=(names)
        # names="music, spotify"
        self.tags = names.split(',').map do |name|
            Tag.where(name: name).first_or_create!
        end
    end
    def all_tags
        tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
    end
end
```

TAG MODEL

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :products, through: :taggings
end
```

TAGGINGS MODEL

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

and this is how i m searching the tags

```
<div id="search-bar">
<%= form_tag products_path, :action=>"index", :method=>"get" do %>
<%= text_field_tag :tag, params[:tag], :name=>"tag", :placeholder=>"   Search Anything", :id=>"s-bar" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search",:name=>"tag", :value=>"search", :style=>"width: 100px; border: none; background: #eee; font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: 5px; display: none;"%>
<%end%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your product model,

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
 tags = Tag.where('LOWER(name) like ?', "#{name.downcase}")
 products = []
 tags.each do |tag|
  products << tag.products
 end
 return products
end
```

This will return an array of products whose tags are similar to the one searched in your text box.

Comment: it got rid of the error but none of the products are showing up

Comment: Do you have the tag (the one you are searching for) in your database?

Comment: yes they are, all seperated by commas (u can check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzx5MrCa0Pc&t=254s) , that how i did it) Please help